# Replacing unicode chracters using a custom replacement method using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I really need your help with this.

I’d like to be able to compare a string against an array and use it to replace special Unicode codes.

```
var unicode_dictionary = {
    "\00E9": "é",
    "\00E0": "à"
}


var old_str = "rapport couvrant une p\00E9riode de 6 mois (f\00E9vrier \00E0 juillet)"

if (\CODE match from the unicode_dictionary is found in the old_str) { then

    replace every single instance of the \CODE with the corresponding
character resulting in the new string:

    var new_str = "rapport couvrant une période de 6 mois (février à juillet)"

}
```

I am really lost with this as my DB outputs unicode characters in the \0000 format. How do I make a custom replace function like the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Regx. in string replace you can achieve this. See the below code

```js
var unicode_dictionary = {
    "\\00E9": "é",
    "\\00E0": "à"
}


var old_str = "rapport couvrant une p\00E9riode de 6 mois (f\00E9vrier \00E0 juillet)"

function convert(){
  for(var key in unicode_dictionary){    
      var regx=new RegExp(key,'g')
      old_str=old_str.replace(regx,unicode_dictionary[key]);
   }
  alert(old_str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='convert()'>Convert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex in combination with its `function` capability: search for the pattern `\\[hex digits]` and replace it with the actual Unicode character, in one pass, for any code. As long as these codes represent valid Unicode characters, the following works:

```
var old_str = "rapport couvrant une p\\00E9riode de 6 mois (f\\00E9vrier \\00E0 juillet)";
var new_str = old_str.replace(/\\([\da-f]{4})/gi, function (a,b)
  {
     return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b, 16));
  });
```

Note that I doubled the backslashes in the source string of the snippet because that is per Javascript rules. The single backslashes in your source text do not need this.

This parses *exactly* 4 hexadecimal characters. If there may be less but no more than 4, you can use the regex `\\([\da-f]{1,4})`. It needs a maximum limit because there is no *end* marker in the source sequence. That means that without the maximum of 4, a string such as

```
the number \\00224\\0022
```

-- intended `the number "4"` -- will be translated as

```
the number Ȥ"
```

because the Unicode codepoint U+0224 represents a capital Z with hook.